# how to combine attask filters

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I've been through the API Docs, but haven't been able to find what I need on this.

How do I combine filters? For example, I need to combine these 2 with logical AND operator:

```
attask/api/project/search?status=Complete&status_Mod=ne

attask/api/project/search?portfolioID=5769a3da00cec1ff3801c15c108df8de&portfolioID_Mod=ne
```

I've tried this, but get an invalid expression error:

```
attask/api/project/search?portfolioID=5769a3da00cec1ff3801c15c108df8de&portfolioID_Mod=ne,status=Complete&status_Mod=ne
```

Also, how about the logical OR operator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your call is failing is not because of the multiple filters but by your status filter you need to filter off the 3 letter code for status not the full word. so status=CPL would work.

To do a OR filter you need to prefix OR:1: before your second filter.
You can continue this by adding OR:2: OR:3: ect...